# Clustering multivariate normal distributions

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, statistics, k-means

I have N multivariate normal distributions. I want to cluster them, so that to remove the redundant ones (the ones which are close enough to each other), or merge them by increasing their sigmas. Is there a method to determine if two given normal distributions are close enough (lets say X% of the points sampled from them will be same, where X is large).

At first I tried using K-Means clustering. As you can see from the picture below, I have drawn the distributions (in the form of ellipses in two choosen dimensions). I passed this through sklearn KMeans. The same colored ones are thought to be same by package.
[image]

I also used the Bhattarcharya distance with the following code I wrote seeing the wikipedia page.

```
def bhattacharya_distance(mu1, mu2, cov1, cov2):
    dist = mu1 - mu2
    sigma = (cov1 + cov2) / 2
    term1 = dist * np.linalg.inv(sigma) * dist.T
    term2 = np.log(np.linalg.det(sigma) / np.sqrt(np.linalg.det(cov1) * np.linalg.det(cov2))) / 2
    return np.exp(-np.linalg.det(term1 + term2))
```

It also fails to identify different gaussians ( or I am doing something wrong).

In the end, I would like to have identified which multi-variate normal distributions are close enough, so that I can possibly merge them and get rid of redundant ones.

Comment: HI, @lokiysh did the below solution work for you? If yes kindly mark it as an accepted answer as this might help others who might visit this page in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [KL Divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) loss for comparing the similarity between two probability distributions. Please follow the example below for more information:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

kl = tf.keras.losses.KLDivergence()

#let's compute the KL divergence between two similar distributions
mean1 = [0, 0]
cov1 = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]  
mean2 = [1, 1]
cov2 = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]  
np.random.seed(10)
x = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean1, cov1, 10)
y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean2, cov2, 10)
kl(x, y).numpy()
2.6799798011779785

#now let's compute the same for two distributions that are far away
mean1 = [0, 0]
cov1 = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]  
mean2 = [5, 5]
cov2 = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]  
np.random.seed(10)
x = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean1, cov1, 10)
y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean2, cov2, 10)
kl(x, y).numpy()
-0.24824540317058563
```

Now you can set a threshold for this metric and group your distributions.